# Setting up Django on a droplet that has Apache installed

Tags: php, python, mysql, django, apache

I have a DigitalOcean droplet that is running Ubuntu and is using Apache and PHP for the web server. I need to move to using Django instead. I already wrote the server using Django. If possible, I'd rather not delete any of the PHP files from the server or delete Apache. How would I go about doing that?

I was also using a MySQL server on Apache. Would you recommend using the default SQLite with Django? Either way, how would I move the data from the old Apache DB to the Django one?

Comment: Have you read the very comprehensive [documentation on deploying with Apache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/)? And I can't imagine why you'd use sqlite if you have MySQL available.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Is there a way to connect my current MySQL database to Django?

Comment: Yes, of course. What are you having trouble with?

Comment: I think that in some cases it's OK (and preferable) to use SQLite on production: http://djangodeployment.com/2016/12/23/which-database-should-i-use-on-production/